# error with serialization in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I use **django rest framework** and have this error:

> `base_name` argument not specified, and could not automatically determine the name from the viewset, as it does not have a `.model` or `.queryset` attribute.

This is my code

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from rest_framework import viewsets, routers
import views

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'book', views.BookViewSet.as_view())
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from mobileapp.models import Book
from rest_framework import generics
from mobileapp.serializers import BookSerializer


class BookViewSet(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Book.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return queryset.order_by('-id')
```

**serializers.py**

```
from mobileapp.models import Book
from rest_framework import serializers


class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'url', 'date', 'comment')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'v solved my problem. There is code.

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from views import BookList, BookDetail
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^book/$',  BookList.as_view(), name='book-list'),
    url(r'^book/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', BookDetail.as_view(), name='book-detail'),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
)

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns, allowed=['json', 'api'])
```

**views.py**

```
class BookList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Book.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        return queryset.order_by('-id')

class BookDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    model = Book
    serializer_class = BookSerializer
```

Comment: Not a very useful answer for other people

Comment: For everybody who does not see the solution taken here, the view "BookViewSet" isn't a Set so you got to register the url yourself, instead of registering it in a router instance. The router can only be used with sets.
more here http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/

Answer (score 1):

Have you google'd error statement?

https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/933

http://django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers.html#usage

Comment: I'v modefied urls.py: router.register(r'^book', views.BookViewSet.as_view(), base_name='book-list'). And now I have 404 error

Comment: with what url? try base_name = 'book', '-list' part is appended by SimpleRouter

Comment: url: localhost:8000/book

Comment: base_name = 'book' also returning 404

Comment: try localhost:8000/book/